# Killing a process on an open socket from another class

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, process

Alright I have a program that opens a socket to a local port and starts processes, the code goes as follows:

> socket_opener.py

```
processes=[]
Handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
Handler.cgi_directories = ["/maps"]
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
httpd.server_name = "localhost"
httpd.server_port = 8008
processes.append(subprocess.Popen("ls"))
processes.append(subprocess.Popen("ls"))
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Now I want to kill a process from the pool of processes in the list `processes` declared above so I tried the following:

> process_killer.py

```
from socket_opener import processes
```

Sadly that's as far as I could go because it throws this error

```
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

What other way can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proximate cause here is that you're running all the code in `socket_opener` again by importing the module. That fails because there's already a socket bound to the port numbered `PORT` and you're attempting to bind another one.

(As far as I can tell, you're adding `server_name` and `server_port` attributes to the object after you've created it that will have no effect on its operation. You really should provide a complete verifiable example ([mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).)

But the bigger problem is that you appear to be operating under the assumption that you can define a list in one program (`socket_opener`) and then access that list from another program (`process_killer`). It doesn't work that way: the first program will be operating in its own process address space separate from that of the second program. The second program won't be able to access variables in the first.

You would need to place the process list in some external object that is accessible from a different program (a file, shared memory segment, or some other IPC [interprocess communication] mechanism). And the form of the list would have to be one that a different program could consume: a textual list of process IDs, say, instead of a python `list` object containing python `Popen` objects, none of which would make sense outside of the originating program's address space.

Comment: Thanks for the effort on the answer, you are right, the objects were bound to the port making it impossible to access. I ended up saving the pid in a database and  retrieving it whenever I needed to kill it.